Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception with message: Unknown database type Springboot 3.3.3
I am upgrading a legacy app from java 8 springboot 1.5.x to java 17 springboot 3.3.3. I was able to sort out things except setting up datasource. The app connects to oracle 19c. I still have couple of cleanup but this is a blocker since I cannot deploy the app without resolving this. Thanks in advance.
application.properties
## oracle
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:xxx
spring.datasource.username=XXX
spring.datasource.password=YYYY
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true

build.gradle: 

plugins { id 'java' id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.3.3' id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.6' id 'jacoco' id 'maven-publish' id 'checkstyle' }

def springBootVersion = '3.3.3' sourceCompatibility = 17 targetCompatibility = 17

configurations { compileOnly { extendsFrom annotationProcessor } }

dependencies { implementation ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:${springBootVersion}") implementation ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:${springBootVersion}") implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBootVersion}") implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:${springBootVersion}") { exclude module: "spring-boot-starter" } implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:${springBootVersion}") { exclude module: "spring-boot-starter" } implementation 'org.springframework:spring-context-support:6.1.12' implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth:3.1.11") { exclude module: "spring-cloud-commons" exclude module: "spring-cloud-starter" } implementation group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.11.0' implementation group: 'com.microsoft.azure.functions', name: 'azure-functions-java-library', version: '3.1.0'

//Oracle jdbc
implementation 'com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc8:23.3.0.23.09'

implementation('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign:3.1.6') {
    exclude module: "spring-cloud-starter"
}
implementation('io.github.openfeign:feign-jackson:13.3') {
    exclude module: "feign-core"
}

compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-collections4', version: '4.5.0-M2'
implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.16.0'
implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:33.3.0-jre'
implementation(group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpcore', version: '4.4.16')
implementation(group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.14')
implementation 'net.sf.dozer:dozer:5.5.1'

implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.17.2'
implementation 'jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:4.0.2'
implementation ('com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:4.0.5') {
    exclude module: "jaxb-core"
}
implementation 'jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:3.1.0'
implementation 'org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:8.0.1.Final'

implementation group: 'com.auth0', name: 'java-jwt', version: '4.4.0'
implementation 'org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:2.0.8'
implementation 'com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:1.24.1'
implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.6.0'
implementation 'org.json:json:20240303'

//test
testImplementation ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:${springBootVersion}") {
    exclude module: "mockito-core"
}
testImplementation 'org.wiremock:wiremock-jetty12:3.9.1'
testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
testImplementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-core:2.0.9'
testImplementation('org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.9'){
    exclude module: "mockito-core"
}
testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:2.0.9'
testImplementation group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '5.13.0'

}

jar { enabled = false }

Exception:

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'asnManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/homedepot/mm/sv/asn/configuration/OracleDBLocalConfig.class]: Failed to initialize dependency 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' of LoadTimeWeaverAware bean 'asnManagerFactory': Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/homedepot/mm/sv/asn/configuration/OracleDBLocalConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception with message: Unknown database type
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:954)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352)
    at com.homedepot.mm.sv.asn.ASNRouterApplication.main(ASNRouterApplication.java:34)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/homedepot/mm/sv/asn/configuration/OracleDBLocalConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception with message: Unknown database type
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:795)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1355)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:313)
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/homedepot/mm/sv/asn/configuration/OracleDBLocalConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception with message: Unknown database type
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:648)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1355)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:904)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:782)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception with message: Unknown database type
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:644)
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unknown database type
    at com.homedepot.mm.sv.asn.configuration.AbstractDataSourceFactory.getDriverClassName(AbstractDataSourceFactory.java:55)
    at com.homedepot.mm.sv.asn.configuration.AbstractDataSourceFactory.setCommonProperties(AbstractDataSourceFactory.java:34)
    at com.homedepot.mm.sv.asn.configuration.OracleDBLocalConfig.dataSource(OracleDBLocalConfig.java:68)
    at com.homedepot.mm.sv.asn.configuration.OracleDBLocalConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$dataSource$2(<generated>)
    at com.homedepot.mm.sv.asn.configuration.OracleDBLocalConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$FastClass$$1.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:258)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:348)
    at com.homedepot.mm.sv.asn.configuration.OracleDBLocalConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.dataSource(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:146)
    ... 35 common frames omitted

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:58526', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1

I would like to establish connection to oracle datasource successfully.

You should take a look into AbstractDataSourceFactory.java:55 as that's not spring's class. I guess it relies on some property which is not there/was changed.
